# Tkinter adding tabs pushes everything to the right

Tags: python, tkinter, tabs, move, shift

Each time I add a new tab, my labels, entry fields, etc... are pushed over to the right [See exmaple here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrG5G.jpg). I have tried different row and column locations for the tabs as well as the label and entry fields without success. I cannot find a solution using grid() instead of pack().

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title(" EXAMPLE ")
        self.root.geometry("220x290-1200-400")
        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self.root)


        self.tab1 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab1, text=" Tab 1 ")

        self.tab2 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab2, text=" Tab 2 ")

        self.tab3 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab3, text=" Tab 3 ")

        self.tab4 = ttk.Frame(self.tabControl)
        self.tabControl.add(self.tab4, text=" Tab 4 ")


        self.tabControl.grid()


        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "blah blah")
        self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="E")

        self.text = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.text.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")

        self.root.mainloop()

Main()
```

Comment: It is because you put `self.tabControl` into row 0 and column 0, so everything in column 1 will be pushed to right when `self.tabControl` is expanding.  Use `columnspan` option, for example, `self.tabControl.grid(columnspan=2)`.  Adjust the number to suit your case.

Answer (score 0):

The notebook is in column zero. `self.label` is also in column 0. A column is the same width from top to bottom. Since `self.label` has `sticky="E"`, it sticks to the right side of column one.

As you add tabs, it makes the notebook widget wider, and that forces the column to be wider. When the column grows, the right edge moves further to the right.

The entry widget is in column 1 which by definition means it's to the right of column 0.

If you want the label and entry widget to be together, and aligned along the left side of the window and under the notebook tabs, I recommend creating a frame that you can put in column 0, directly under the notebook. Then, put the label and entry in the frame using either `pack` or `grid`.

Answer (score 0):

Used `grid` should problem. And Add `columnspan=2` in `tabControl`.

Snippet:

```
self.tabControl.grid(columnspan=2)


self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text = "blah blah")
self.label.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")

self.text = tk.Entry(self.root)
self.text.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")
```

Output:

[image]